# 2-3 trees, data storage

Tags: algorithm, tree

hello everyone I'm trying to understand how 2-3 trees work, I understood a concept about keys, but where do I actually store data itself, only in leaves, or in nodes with 1 key (internal node), and 2 keys (internal node) also, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on this tree structure but the first sentence from the Wikipedia page on [2-3 Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3_tree) seems to answer your question about where the data is stored:

> A 2-3 tree in computer science is a
>   type of data structure, a tree where
>   every node with children (internal
>   node) has either two children and one
>   data element (2-nodes) or three
>   children and two data elements
>   (3-nodes).

Seems to me you store data in each node of the tree. The Wiki page also has a link to a [Java Applet demonstrating inserts](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/mukundan/dsal/TwoThreeTree.html).

EDIT: After reading your comment, and having another look for some sample code, I'm inclined to think your data and key (as you are calling it) are the same thing (as Chowlett has mentioned in their answer).

Looking at this [sample code](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/twothree.html) (they are only storing ints) I would create a twoThreeNode class which holds pointers to the data you are storing, ensuring the data class has overloaded comparison operators to allow them to be sorted. Then follow the algorithm as before.

I found an interesting article, with source code, here: [Balanced Trees, Part 2: Interior 2-3 Trees](http://www.teachsolaisgames.com/articles/balanced23interior.html)

Comment: thanks, but I've read it, and it seems that wiki is talking about keys, but not data.

Comment: @rookie: From running the Java app it appeared to me the data is stored in each node but that example is only using numbers. I assume you are considering that data as a 'key' and then you want to sore additional data (via a pointer, for example). Am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: yeap, exactly, I want to know where am I supposed to store these pointers, only in leaves or in internal nodes also... how do You think?

Comment: @rookie: I edited my answer to add some more information; I would create a key/data class which overloads the comparison operators allowing you to compare the data and order the tree correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples where data itself is only stored in the leaves, and the internal nodes store signposts (see *Data Structures and Algorithms*, by Aho, Hopcroft & Ullman)i

The data structure, insertion and deletion algorithms are the same (but for the details), and while the space req'd might be double the examples listed above, the tree's height would only increase by 1, so, you still have the very nice look-up times.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used this data structure; but the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3_tree) is pretty clear.

The data is stored as the 1 or 2 fields on every node, internal or leaf; I think what you're calling "keys" is exactly the data that you're trying to store. Each internal node with 2 children has a single data item; that item is greater-than all the items descended from its left child, and less-than-or-equal all the items descended from its right child (`left < data <= right`). In the case of a 3-child node, the data is such that: `left < data_1 <= middle < data_2 <= right`.